# Print external host name of EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I can get the internal hostname of an instance with the `hostname` command. How do I get the external host name from within the instance?

Specifically I'm on EY and using the `ey ssh` command, I want to know what the host name is so I can pass this to scp.

Answer (score 13):

From within the instance, you can hit the [Instance Metadata Service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html?r=257):

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

or

```
curl http://instance-data.ec2.internal/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

A wide variety of data is available via this interface.

Comment: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: instance-data.ec2.internal`

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau And did you try the IP-based approach?

Comment: No, IPs change and can't be relied upon indefinitely. Ended up using a combination of `ec2metadata` and `nslookup`

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau `169.254.169.254` isn't likely to change on the AWS end.

Comment: It doesn't matter how unlikely it is, if it is possible and it is avoidable then it is an unnecessary failure point.

Answer (score 7):

`/opt/aws/bin/ec2-metadata -p` will print the public hostname of that instance.

Comment: `-bash: /opt/aws/bin/ec2-metadata: No such file or directory`
- Instead use `ec2metadata --public-hostname` as described by @calvin-huang below

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple by [ec2 instance metadata query tool](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1825?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1).

run command:

```
./ec2-metadata --public-ipv4
```

or:

```
./ec2-metadata --public-hostname
```

for more information, just pass --help to ec2-metadata

Comment: `-bash: ./ec2-metadata: No such file or directory`
instead use `ec2metadata --public-hostname` as described by @calvin-huang below

Answer (score 2):

Currently, on EC2 instances you can use:

```
$ ec2metadata --public-hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what system you use but I assume a Linux. You can either connect directly to your IP address or try a reverse lookup of this ip with for example

```
host -a <ip_address>
```

You can find out your IP address if you use the command `ifconfig` that will print out all information on the network interfaces.

Comment: If the host name is unknown, it is highly likely that the IP address is also unknown (at least, by whatever script is trying to find it).

Answer (score 0):

```
public_hostname=$(timeout 2 ec2metadata --public-hostname 2> /dev/null)
if [ -z "$public_hostname" ]; then # fallback to nslookup + hostname
    public_hostname=$(nslookup "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')" | awk '/name/{print $NF}' | sed 's/\.$//')
fi
```